# how to read rss feed to gae-database 

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, rss

any gae-lib to do this

i think maybe  jquery can do this too , yes ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to avoid the hassle of polling, error handling, parsing, handling invalid feeds, and so on and so forth, by making someone else do it for you. [This blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Consuming-RSS-feeds-with-PubSubHubbub) describes how you can use PubSubHubbub to do the bulk of the work on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a list of Python RSS processing libraries available by searching "python rss" in google.com](http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries)